# IntelliJ - access is denied

Tags: android, eclipse, intellij-idea

I am building an Android application using Eclipse IDE Helios Service Release 2 for TFS integration but need to now use IntelliJ IDE. I am able to port the project just fine into IntelliJ, but am not able to run it due to a permissions issue with the file system that I believe is being caused by eclipse since I can't alter or delete the files using the OS either (Windows 7).

Output while buiding with IntelliJ:

error while writing [file] : [location] (Access is denied)

Windows gives a similar error when attempting to delete any files. (Cannot delete [file]: Access is denied.

It isn't a TFS issue either since the files I am altering/deleting aren't in the Source Control.

Comment: Update: I already thought of that possibility and tried deleting the files just after start up. I looked at the running processes & nothing should have been "using" those files.

I ended up creating another TFS workspace for my project & used that instead. It seemed the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating another TFS workspace for my project & used that instead. It seemed the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

Most of time this kind of "permissions issue" on Windows is actually due to the filesystem "feature" such that you can't delete to files while they're open for reading or writing. Building normally means deleting the old, generating the new. Can you think of anything that may be holding the offending file(s) open?